# Long loop vs short loop Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops

Using the below code as an example, could someone give me an example of a one liner code for a loop method and explain to me the difference? I know there is a short vs long version of a loop and I think this would be helpful for community search (and my own understanding).

```
def first_square_numbers(number_of_squares)
  squares = []

  idx = 0
   while idx < number_of_squares
   squares.push(idx * idx)
    idx = idx + 1
  end

  return squares
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one where you can just use the block capability of the `Array` constructor:

```
def first_square_numbers(number_of_squares)
  Array.new(number_of_squares) { |i| i * i }
end
```

This creates an array of the desired size, and then applies the supplied block to evaluate each index location `i` as specified, in this case squaring the index value.  See the [`Array` docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-c-new) for details.

Comment: Even better, omit `squares=` since that's never used.

Comment: @tadman Good call, thanks.  I tested it initially without embedding it in a method...

Answer (score 5):

```
def f x
  (0...x).map { |n| n * n }
end
```

Comment: ranges are enumerable so you shouldn't need the `.to_a` here.

Comment: This will generate a warning: the `x` within the block is shadowing the outer `x`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this applies to blocks not loops.  Loops constructs are often passed a block (for the loop to perform).  The difference is using either a set of curly braces `{}` or a `do` ... `end` keyword block.  The syntax difference is specifically for code that fits within one line vs. multiple lines [bbatsov/ruby-style-guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#single-line-blocks).

Loops require an end statement so there is no "short" version of them, either include the do keyword or don't.

#### Short

```
for x in (0...5)
  p x
end
```

#### Long

```
for x in (0...5) do
  p x
end
```

Comment: There is no (explicit) block. The `do` here is just a `then` for loop keywords.

Comment: I was trying to call out that Enumerable are not loops, but failed to articulate it.